# Jenkins plugins download failure for application which supports Jenkins 2.346 version with java 8

Tags: jenkins

My application is running on jenkins 2.346 version with java 8. while trying to connect with jenkins server multiple plugins are not getting installed.

Application details are as below -

Java 8
tomcat 9 server
war file of jenkins 2.346.3 is deployed in tomcat/webapps/jenkins.war

Firslty I have installed java 8 then tomcat 9 and deployed war of jenkins 2.346.3 in tomcat/webapps.

Gave executable permission to tomcat and executed ./startup.sh file from tomcat/bin.

Connected with jenkins server by using initial password but while installing recommeded plugins by community multiple plugins are not getting installed.

I want solutions for this.